# Duplicate rows showing up in the query with join operation

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I am writing this query

```
SELECT aw_offers_v3.id,aw_offers_v3.name 
FROM aw_offers_v3,aw_countries_v3,aw_categories_v3 
WHERE aw_offers_v3.id = aw_countries_v3.id 
AND aw_offers_v3.id = aw_categories_v3.id 
AND ( aw_offers_v3.api_key = 'a2a9e134bcb7935ecb6a1d989110650c016c91f17835d733aebd113255b4abb1' ) 
AND ( aw_offers_v3.network_id = 'http://api.hasoffers.com/v3/Affiliate_Offer.json' ) 
AND ( aw_countries_v3.country = 'Albania' OR aw_countries_v3.country = 'Armenia' ) 
AND ( aw_categories_v3.category = 'Casual' )
```

I am getting this result

```
|--------------------------------------|
|     id         |        name         |
|--------------------------------------|
|     11105      |        APP 3        |
|----------------|---------------------|
|     11107      |        APP 4        |
|----------------|---------------------|
|     11105      |        APP 3        |
|--------------------------------------|
|     11107      |        APP 4        |
|----------------|---------------------|
```

I don't know why I am getting this duplicate result. There's no duplicate data in the actual tables.

Here's my aw_offers_v3

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|     id         |        name         |        Desc       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|     391        |        APP 1        |       A           |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|     234        |        APP 2        |       B           |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|     11105      |        APP 3        |       bb          |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|     11107      |        APP 4        |       thut        |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
```

Here's my aw_countries_v3

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|  internal_id   |      country        |        id         |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|      1         |      Albania        |       11105       |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|      2         |      Armenia        |       11105       |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|      3         |     Argentina       |       11105       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|      4         |      Albania        |       11107       |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|      5         |      Armenia        |       11107       |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|      6         |       Andola        |       11107       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

Here's my aw_categories_v3

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|  internal_id   |      category       |        id         |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|      1         |      Android        |       11105       |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|      2         |       Casual        |       11105       |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|      3         |       Sports        |       11105       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|      4         |       Gamimg        |       11107       |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|      5         |       Casual        |       11107       |
|----------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|      6         |       Sports        |       11107       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: did you try this? `group by aw_offers_v3.name`

Comment: nope. i didnt use group by....

Comment: i think group by can fix your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.name 
FROM aw_offers_v3 a 
INNER JOIN aw_countries_v3 b ON a.id = b.id 
INNER JOIN aw_categories_v3 c ON a.id = c.id 
WHERE a.api_key = 'a2a9e134bcb7935ecb6a1d989110650c016c91f17835d733aebd113255b4abb1' AND 
      a.network_id = 'http://api.hasoffers.com/v3/Affiliate_Offer.json' AND 
      b.country IN ('Albania', 'Armenia') AND c.category = 'Casual'
```

Comment: one thing i want to tell, if you are not using Distinct in your query, then its giving the same duplicate rows as i was getting previously.... if i put Distinct in my query, then i am getting no duplicate rows.... so whats the point in using inner join?

Comment: ok, actualy i generaly dont use JOIN keywords... anyways thanks... by the way, can u explain me why we are getting duplicate rows if we are not using DISTINCT

Comment: @Saswat The original query has inner joins. It just uses the older, implicit syntax of listing all the tables in the `FROM` clause. The performance is the same, this is just the preferred syntax these days.

Comment: @Saswat You get duplicates because you have multiple countries with the same `id`. Each one produces a row in the results.